# Migrate WebForm VB to MVC .NET core 2.2

Tags: c#, vb.net, model-view-controller, migrate, clean-architecture

We currently have an WebForm Website written en Net2. We want moving it to MVC in NET core 2.2. We can not migrate it directly because of business impacts and the huge number of features. Current website using ajax and we want keep all ajax from .net 2.0 to .net core 2.2.

Our idea is to develop one or more new website in MVC .Net core 2.2 (with a new architecture). And we want design clean architecture and using it to design mvc solution and using it to deploy to Azure or AWS.

Can you confirm to me it is a good approach ?

Thanks.

Comment: This is not a question for SO, which is for specific programming issues, not general approaches.

Comment: Why not .net core 3? Depending how well your older project is written, you could import the business logic into a new app (conversion willing). But this might be one of those cases when you need to cut and run. Anyway too broad and offtopic for SO

Comment: Because .net core 2.2 have long term support from microsoft. And we have not idea for move UI from webform to razor page and apply ajax for UI because UI of webform depent on business?